# Using and statements to create Boolean iterate over rows

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, boolean, and-operator

I want to go through all rows of my data frame to see if a data point falls within the range of two values. If the data point lies in the correct range for the `x` coordinate and `y` than the column `etData['3_1']` should display a True in that row.

for index in etData.iterrows():
if ((etData['lr_x'] >= -0.49) & (etData['lr_x'] >=-0.31)) & ((etData['lr_y'] >= 0.31) & (etData['lr_y'] >=0.49)):
etData['3_1']= True

This is the code I got. I keep getting an error: through value of a series is ambiguous.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you mean `<= -0.31` and `<= 0.49`?

Comment: you can't use `and`/`or` with Series, you need the bitwise operators `&`/`|`